# PyQt5 signal communication between worker thread and main window is not working correctly

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I'm creating an application with PyQt5, which has a very simple user interface. There is a dropdown list from which a value can be chosen, and then there is a button which can be clicked on and an action will be performed based on a current value in the dropdown list.

Currently if I run the code below, I can get a value from the dropdown list and it will be emitted to worker thread before `myaction.myaction(customer_name)` is run. The code also runs fine, but the GUI is not working the way I want it to work while the function in worker thread runs. When I click on the **start** button, it should emit a signal to the GUI to disable the button, change its label and color, but that never happens. When the function finishes, it should be changed back to its original form.

Is the problem how I handle signals, or am I having redundant functions in my classes? What is the correct way to send that dropdown list value to worker thread everytime the button is clicked, so I can simply use it as a variable there?

Every possible solution to this I find online gets me excited but none of them have been working for me yet, or some of them have been too confusing for me to understand.

Here's some answers I've already gone through

- [PyQt get value from GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744783/pyqt-get-value-from-gui)
- [Updating variable values when running a thread using QThread in PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781548/updating-variable-values-when-running-a-thread-using-qthread-in-pyqt4)
- [Sending a signal from main function to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293556/sending-a-signal-from-main-function-to-a-thread)

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
#import myaction
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QComboBox, QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class ConfWorker(QtCore.QThread):
    updated_button = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)
    updated_label = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    updated_error = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    request_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    customer = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ConfWorker, self).__init__(parent)
        self.customer.connect(self.getcustomer)

    def run(self):
        self.request_signal.emit()

    def getcustomer(self, text):
        self.configure(text)

    def configure(self, customer_name):
        self.updated_button.emit(["In progress...", False])
        self.updated_label.emit(customer_name)
        time.sleep(5) # During this time you should be able to see color change etc.
        #myaction.myaction(customer_name)# TAKES ~20 SECONDS TO FINISH
        self.updated_button.emit(["Start", True])

class ConfGUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ConfGUI, self).__init__()

        self.worker = ConfWorker(self)
        self.worker.updated_button.connect(self.updateButton)
        self.worker.updated_label.connect(self.updateLabel)
        self.worker.updated_error.connect(self.updateError)
        self.worker.request_signal.connect(self.sendCustomer)

        self.targetBtn = QPushButton('Start Configuration', self)
        self.targetBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: green; color: white }"
                        "QPushButton:disabled { background-color: red; color: white }")
        self.targetBtn.clicked.connect(self.worker.start)
        self.targetBtn.setGeometry(100, 400, 200, 50)
        self.setGeometry(800, 300, 400, 550)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 550)

        self.customerlist = QComboBox(self)
        self.customerlist.setGeometry(100, 50, 200, 50)
        self.customerlist.setObjectName("customer")
        self.customerlist.addItem("testcustomer1")
        self.customerlist.addItem("testcustomer2")
        self.customerlist.addItem("testcustomer3")

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setStyleSheet('font-size: 30pt; font-family: Courier; color: green;')
        self.label.setGeometry(70,250,400,50)

        self.error_label = QLabel(self)
        self.error_label.setText("")
        self.error_label.setStyleSheet('font-size: 30pt; font-family: Courier; color: red;')
        self.error_label.setGeometry(70,350,400,50)

        self.show()

    def sendCustomer(self):
        self.worker.customer.emit(self.customerlist.currentText())

    def updateButton(self, button_list):
        self.targetBtn.setText(button_list[0])
        self.targetBtn.setEnabled(button_list[1])

    def updateLabel(self, label_text):
        self.label.setText(label_text)

    def updateError(self, error_text):
        self.error_label.setText(error_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ConfGUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You can share the module `myaction.py`

Comment: @S.Nick What do you mean?

Comment: import myaction    ???

Comment: @S.Nick Oh sorry that's just my own module that I'm not allowed to share! If you want to test it, you can just replace it with `time.sleep(n)` and maybe emit customer_name to GUI. The same problem will still exist. I made changes so it can be run without importing the module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by a very common and wrong conception, they think that QThread is a *Qt Thread*, that is, a new thread made by Qt, but no, `QThread` is a thread **handler** as indicated in [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details):

> The QThread class provides a platform-independent way to manage
>   threads.
>
> A QThread object manages one thread of control within the program.
>   QThreads begin executing in run(). By default, run() starts the event
>   loop by calling exec() and runs a Qt event loop inside the thread.

The only part that runs on another thread is the run method, and in your case you are not calling because your logic is different, you do not want to continuously execute a heavy task but at the user's request, so design must be that of a worker but you are using a QThread as the base class, and that is incorrect, you must use a QObject as a base class and move it to a new thread so that the QObject does its tasks in that thread, preventing the GUI from blocking.

A QObject is not thread-safe, it lives in a thread, and the thread where it is determined by the following:

- A `QObject` lives in the parent's thread
- If you do not have a parent, live in the thread where it was created unless you have moved to another thread.
- And you can move to another thread with the `moveToThread()` function, but `moveToThread()` will fail if the `QObject` has a parent since the first criterion is privileged.

On the other hand if you want to call a method from another thread it is necessary that you use the decorator `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()`

---

Considering the above, we obtain the following solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class ConfWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    updated_button = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)
    updated_label = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    updated_error = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    request_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    customer = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ConfWorker, self).__init__(parent)
        self.customer.connect(self.getcustomer)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def doWork(self):
        self.request_signal.emit()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def getcustomer(self, text):
        self.configure(text)

    def configure(self, customer_name):
        self.updated_button.emit(["In progress...", False])
        self.updated_label.emit(customer_name)
        time.sleep(5) # During this time you should be able to see color change etc.
        #myaction.myaction(customer_name)# TAKES ~20 SECONDS TO FINISH
        self.updated_button.emit(["Start", True])

class ConfGUI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ConfGUI, self).__init__()

        # create a QThread and start the thread that handles
        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        thread.start()

        # create the worker without a parent so you can move
        self.worker = ConfWorker()
        # the worker moves to another thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(thread)

        self.worker.updated_button.connect(self.updateButton)
        self.worker.updated_label.connect(self.updateLabel)
        self.worker.updated_error.connect(self.updateError)
        self.worker.request_signal.connect(self.sendCustomer)

        self.targetBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start Configuration', self)
        self.targetBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: green; color: white }"
                        "QPushButton:disabled { background-color: red; color: white }")
        self.targetBtn.clicked.connect(self.worker.doWork)
        self.targetBtn.setFixedSize(200, 50)

        self.customerlist = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.customerlist.addItems(["testcustomer1", "testcustomer2", "testcustomer3"])
        self.customerlist.setFixedSize(200, 50)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet('font-size: 30pt; font-family: Courier; color: green;')
        self.label.setFixedSize(400,50)

        self.error_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.error_label.setStyleSheet('font-size: 30pt; font-family: Courier; color: red;')
        self.error_label.setFixedSize(400,50)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.customerlist, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(self.label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(self.error_label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(self.targetBtn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 550)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def sendCustomer(self):
        self.worker.customer.emit(self.customerlist.currentText())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(list)
    def updateButton(self, button_list):
        self.targetBtn.setText(button_list[0])
        self.targetBtn.setEnabled(button_list[1])

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def updateLabel(self, label_text):
        self.label.setText(label_text)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def updateError(self, error_text):
        self.error_label.setText(error_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ConfGUI()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Observation:** Also, as you can see in my solution, `QThread` will be a child of the window, because `QThread` is a `QObject` that handles another thread.

Answer (score 2):

You really write very difficult simple things.
Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QComboBox, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QThread, pyqtSignal

class ConfWorker(QThread):
    threadSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    finishSignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, startParm):
        super().__init__()
        self.startParm = startParm   # Initialize the parameters passed to the task 

    def run(self):
        # Do something...
        for i in range(20):
            text = "In progress ................." \
                    if i%2==0 else "In progress {}".format(self.startParm)
            self.threadSignal.emit(text)
            QThread.msleep(500)
        self.finishSignal.emit(self.startParm)


class ConfGUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(800, 100, 400, 550)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 550)        

        self.targetBtn = QPushButton('Start Configuration', self)
        self.targetBtn.setStyleSheet(
                        "QPushButton { background-color: green; color: white;}"
                        "QPushButton:disabled { background-color: red; color: white;}"
                        )
        self.targetBtn.setGeometry(100, 400, 200, 50)
        self.targetBtn.clicked.connect(self.workerStart)           

        self.customerlist = QComboBox(self)
        self.customerlist.setGeometry(100, 50, 200, 50)
        self.customerlist.setObjectName("customer")
        self.customerlist.addItem("testcustomer1")
        self.customerlist.addItem("testcustomer2")
        self.customerlist.addItem("testcustomer3")
        self.customerlist.activated[str].connect(self.comboActivated)
        self.startParm = "testcustomer1"

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet('font-size: 30pt; font-family: Courier; color: green;')
        self.label.setGeometry(70,250,400,50)

    def workerStart(self):
        self.targetBtn.setText("In progress...")
        self.targetBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.worker = ConfWorker(self.startParm)  
        self.worker.threadSignal.connect(self.on_threadSignal)
        self.worker.finishSignal.connect(self.on_finishSignal)        
        self.worker.start()                     

    def on_threadSignal(self, text):
        self.targetBtn.setText(text)

    def on_finishSignal(self, text):
        self.targetBtn.setEnabled(True)
        self.targetBtn.setText("Start Configuration'")
        self.label.setText(text)

    def comboActivated(self, text):
        self.startParm = text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex  = ConfGUI()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Your design is different from what the OP asks, you are using to overwrite the run method of QThread, which is a simple but limited design, for example let's say you have n-tasks that are executed on user demand and that are heavy and that they will not run one after the other, their methodology will fail. There is a better design that is to create a worker that will live in another thread and execute each task in that new thread without blocking the GUI. In conclusion, your design is simple but limited.